# How to keep data or params on refresh or changing browser (passing link) angular 13

Tags: angular

I have a problem trying to pass a value to another component using a service. I want to keep the values o bring the nid of the data without having to go back to parent component. Local/Session storage works but only in the same browser/computer but if i want to give the link to another person the nid will return undefined.

Here's my code...

```
//html
<a routerLink="/informes/{{alias[i]}}" (click)="setNid(nid[i])" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
```

i call the function setNid and pass to service

```
//1st.component
setNid(nid: any) {
  console.log(nid);
  this.buscadorService.nid = nid;
}

//1st.service
    nid: string | any;
```

i store the value of the variable in service to pass to another component

```
//2nd.component
this.nid = this.buscadorService.nid;
console.log(this.nid);
```

But if i reload the page or open it on another browser it gives undefined... And i want to show the alias variable not the nid in the url...

I managed to do it with something like this

```
<a routerLink="/informes/{{nid[i]}}" (click)="setNid(nid[i])" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2"> 

//2nd.component
this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
  // console.log(params['nid']) ;
  this.buscadorService.nid = params['nid'];
});
```

But to do this i have to show the nid in the url and i don't want that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you refresh a page or open a page in a new tab, it loads/reloads the entire angular app from scratch, which is why you have no value.  If you want to make that value persistent and visible to another instance of your angular app, you will need to either store it so the other app can access it, or pass it on to the other instance.  I would recommend localStorage, but you could use a cookie as well, or on the URL as you already indicated.

Comment: But how can i pass to another instance. Could you give me an example? I tried passing the value to another component and store there but didnt work. Thanks!!!